# New to R and need to count the amount of time I have run the while loop

Tags: r, function

The below function I suppose to simulate $n$ $N (0,1)$ random variates using the Accept-Reject algorithm with a Cauchy candidate. I hope it is correct.

```
ar.normal<-function(n){
x<-double(n) 
i<-1
while(i<(n+1)){  # this is to make sure we continue until we fill our x vector
C<-rcauchy(1) 
u<-runif(1)
temp<-(M^(-1))*(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-C^2/2)/(1/(pi*(1+C^2)))
if(u<-temp){
  x[i]<-C
  i<-i+1
}
}
return(list(x,i))
}
```

I need to know how many times I have gone to my while function in order to get 1000 draws that worked in my condition which is u<-temp. and it stored in x vector. I do not know how I can count that.

Comment: so if you run your function as `result <- ar.normal(n)`, the `result` variable will store both `x` (in `result[1]`) and `i` (in `result[2]`). Or you wanted something else?

Comment: by the way, `M` is not defined in your function - be carefult where you want to take it from. Also, what did you mean by `if(u<-temp)` construct? - which condition are you checking?